# Transition from view (one of the options) in slide out menu to another option in menu with button press and WITH navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, viewcontroller, saslidemenu

For testing purposes, I'm using the demo that's provided on Github. Search SASlideMenu to find the github repo.

Screenshot 1:
[image]
Screenshot 2:
[image]

Ok, so I'm using SASlideMenu in my app and here is what I want to do:

In a nutshell, I want to go from the blue page (the one with the button that says "Press me to get to screenshot 1") with a button press, to another one of the options in the menu. I've added the option to get to screenshot 1 to the menu and clicking on this it takes me to that view WITH the navigation bar at the top.

The problem is, when I press the "Press me to get to Screenshot 1" button, it takes me to the screenshot 1 page without the navigation bar at the top of the view. I've used a modal segue to link the button to the view shown in screenshot 1.

I want this view to have the navigation bar just like in the blue screenshot.

Is this possible?

I hope this is clear. If you need any clarification, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse that top bar in different view's as it is here

But following may be solution

*1.* If top bar is navigation bar then use push segue instead of modal and setup buttons again

*2.*    If you want to use same top bar, just mimic modal view presentation by writing custom segue

//code to mimic modal presetation will be similar to this

```
- (void)perform
{

    //add as subview with origin y at bottom -50 
    CGRect frame = [[self destinationViewController] view].frame;
    frame.origin.y = [[self sourceViewController] view].frame.size.height -50;
    [[self destinationViewController] view].frame = frame;


    [[[self sourceViewController] view] addSubview:[[self destinationViewController] view]];

    //animate frame with new y postion
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        CGRect frame = [[self destinationViewController] view].frame;
        frame.origin.y =[[self sourceViewController] view].frame.origin.y - SOME_OFFSET_VALUE_TO_SHOW_TOP_BAR;
        [[self destinationViewController] view].frame = frame;

    }];
}
```

*3*. If you dont wan't modal segue, then just use custom segue like in 2. and add your view (white one) as subview in area below navigation bar

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. I want to transition to another view that is already in the menu. i.e. it's an option in the menu. I want the button to go to the same place. If there's an option "view" in the menu, when I click view, it will take me to a page with a navigation bar at the top just like in the blue screenshot. I want the button in the blue screenshot to go to the SAME view.